# Getting Null pointer Exception while String comparision

Tags: java, string, jsp

I have written a simple login module in jsp (a lot of scriplets are there :) ). But, i am continuously getting  NullPointer exception error. I am not able to find, i tried a lot.

JSP Login code

```
<form action="loginAction.jsp" method="post" name="config-form">
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td> UserName:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" required parameter=*"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="username" required parameter=*"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="LogIn"></td></tr>
</table>
```

LoginAction.jsp

```
<body>
<%
    String username=request.getParameter("username");
    String password=request.getParameter("password");


    LoginModel login = new LoginModel();
    login.setUsername(username);
    login.setPassword(password);

    LoginValidator validator = new LoginValidator();
    boolean validate=validator.validateLogin(login);

    if(validate==false)
    {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }
    else
    {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }

%>
```

LoginModel.java

```
public class LoginModel {
private String username;
private String password;
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

LoginValidator.java

```
public boolean validateLogin(LoginModel login)
{
    String uname="vivekaltruist";
    String passwd="somePassword";
    System.out.println(login.getUsername());
    if((login.getUsername().equals(uname)) && login.getPassword().equals(passwd))
    {
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}
```

The Stacktrace:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at LoginValidator.validateLogin(LoginValidator.java:12)

I am sure, it will be a silly reason,but i am not able to find it. The same thing, i tried without jsp, its working fine.
Help me out

Comment: I am fearing that, i might get downvoted for this. i am new to JSP, a lot of scriplets are also there. I know, its bad practice, i will change that

Comment: The main reason why you might get downvoted is for not identifying line 12, though in this case there's only one line that could raise the exception.  login is null, or getUsername or getPassword is returning null.

Comment: It is better you get hold of the essence of NPE and reason it is generated. It will be really helpful for you to pin point it's origin if you know what it means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've named your password input parameter `username` too

```
<td><input type="password" name="username" required parameter=*"></td>
```

This

```
String password=request.getParameter("password");
```

will return `null` because there is no request parameter identified by `password` and eventually cause a `NullPointerException` when you try to get it and call `equals()` on it. Change its `name` attribute to `"password"`.

Comment: @sotirious Yes..I knew that there will be a silly problem. I was trying a lot, reading Stacktaces and all. 
Should i delete the post from here as it is not useful for anyone for sure

Comment: @user Sure, if that's your opinion.

Comment: @user1969412: Even though your post contextually applies to you, the question provides that context and the answer serves to illustrate the issue. Personally I'd leave it to help others

Answer (score 0):

The problem here

```
<td><input type="text" name="username" required parameter=*"></td>
<td><input type="password" name="username" required parameter=*"></td>
```

Your tows field have same name.While processing,there is not password value gotten